# Suppose that i sub $n = 5%$ for all $n ≥ 1$. How long will it take an investment to triple in value?

Tags: finance

Suppose that i sub $n = 5%$ for all $n ≥ 1$. How long will it take an investment to triple in value?

I tried to use $3x=x(e^{.05t})$

then i got $\ln3+\ln x=\ln x+.05t$

so $t=\ln(3)/.05 = 21.97$

but i know that the answer is $22.5171$

Comment: Please use MathJax (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for future post.

Comment: what does $n$ mean?

Answer (score 2):

The discrepancy in the value is due to the use of continuous compounding than the discrete compounding.

So $3X = X(1+.05)^t$

Taking logarithm on both sides, you get $\ln(3) = t\ln(1.05)$

$t = \ln(3)/\ln(1.05) = 22.5171$

There you go!!

I still wonder what n is? and x_n is ?

Goodluck

Answer (score 1):

You will use the formula

$$A = P(1 + (r/n))nt$$

where:
$A$ = accumulated amount
$P$ = investment
$t$ = time
$r$ = interest rate
$n$ = number of times compounded per year

$$P = P$$
$$A = 3P$$
$$r = 0.05$$
$$n = 1$$
$$t = 1$$

Substituting these values into the formula,

$$3P = P(1 + 0.05)t$$

Divide by  $P$ on both sides of the equation.

$$3 = 1.05t$$

Log both sides of the equation

$$\log(3) = \log(1.05)t$$

Bring the exponent t down as the coefficient of the log(1.05)

$$\log(3) = t \log(1.05)$$

Divide by $log(1.05)$ into both sides of the equation

$$t = \log(3) / \log(1.05)$$
$$t = 22.52$$

It will take $22.52$ years to triple the investment at an interest rate of $5$%.